# Representing Information Using ASCII

Tags: ascii

I just have a question to make sure I get something well.

If I used my computer to sum 10+11 which is 21, it will store 21 in usually a byte such that `0001 0101`, however, when it prints it on the screen, it will actually represent it as two digits 2 (`0110010`) and 1 (`0110001`) appended to each other to form 21) using ASCII.

**Is that right?**

Thank you!

Comment: `0001 0101` is only 1 Byte (= 8 Bit), not 2 Bytes as you stated.

Comment: Yes. How many bytes it will use for internal representation depends on the data type you use though.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier, sorry my mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

The representation of characters in a simple terminal is ASCII, where each character is represented by a (technically 7-bit) code.

Some terminals support more complex encodings like UTF8, but since UTF8 is backwards compatible with ASCII you need not worry about it.

Comment: I was just a little bit confused about the numbers being represented in more than one way. Now I get that representing numbers in terminal or a screen in general is a completely different thing from representing them in the process the computer uses for arithmetic. Thank you!